# Negative qty on credit memo PDF printout

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, creditmemo

I need to have the quantity on the Credit Memo PDF printout with a negative sign.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items of a credit memo PDF are rendered in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Creditmemo_Default`, around line 77.

Rewrite the model from a custom extension and change

```
$lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $item->getQty() * 1,
            'feed'  => 445,
            'font'  => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        );
```

to

```
$lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $item->getQty() * -1,
            'feed'  => 445,
            'font'  => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        );
```

Rewriting can be done in the `config.xml`

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    [...]
    <global>
       <models>
          <sales>
              <rewrite>
                  <order_pdf_items_creditmemo_default>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Creditmemo_Default</order_pdf_items_creditmemo_default>
              </rewrite>
          </sales>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

you're custom class extending the origional one

Comment: Thanks, I managed to modify the qty and row totals to have a negative sign before the value. How can I add a negative sign to the totals as well?